# Finding infinite nested elements of table with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

[Quote chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzk50.png)

Hi,

Site url is :[The is the URL](https://forum.donanimhaber.com/dunya-duzdur-ciddiyim-aksini-kanitlayana-yemek-ismarliyorum--122404780-2)
I'm scraping replies from this site and I'm stuck with these quotes in quotes.

```
REPLY = "//div[@class='icerik']"
answers = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, REPLY)))
answers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(REPLY)
for answer in answers:

    cell = answer.find_elements_by_class_name("msg")
    if len(cell) != 0:
        for c in cell:
            c.find_element_by_tag_name("td")
            print("..........Mesajın basi...............\n")
            print(c.text)
            print("\n")
            print("..........Mesajın sonu...............\n")
            print("######################################\n")
        else:
            continue
```

I can scrap either quotes and replies but I want them seperately. 
Quote chain can be infinite in this situation. I've tried various xpaths for REPLY but I couldn't find a solution. With REPLY xpath scrap both quotes and reply itself.

Shortly, I want to scrap reply itself and these quotes one by one with different strings.

Thanks for answers.
Here is HTML code of this quote chain.
[Quote HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPk6s.png)

Comment: Update the question with the definition of `QUOTES` as in `By.XPATH, QUOTES`

Comment: Please elaborate what is the quote and what is your XPath?

Comment: Can you update the question with what exactly you mean by `I can scrap either quotes and replies but I want them seperately`? What output are you expecting? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to scrap reply itself and these quotes one by one with different strings.